# Finding multiple as part of one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Invoice which has LineItems and each LineItem has a Part_No which is from Product.

How can I write Sql to find invoices that have 2 different Part_No; i.e. Part_No 1234 and 2345?

I'm not sure how to even begin this one...

Sql for MS Sql Server is preferred but not a must.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approach these problems using `group by` and `having`:

```
select invoiceid
from lineitems li
where part_no in (1234, 2345)
group by invoiceid
having count(distinct part_no) = 2;
```